# Unable to operate on postgres SQL installed with jasper server

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I installed jasperserver with bundled postgresql and bundled Tomcat. I am able to launch server successfully. when I open PG Admin-III from jaspersoft folder in c:/programfile/.. its opening successfully. But, its not showing any database there and even I am not able to create any db as there is no server. Can someone help me for this. Do I need to add server manually in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

you must manually create database connection in PG Admin. Don't forget to configure Client authentication in pg_hba.conf